# Spring boot : How to read application.properties consistently?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm a beginner using Spring boot and I have some problems reading properties from **application.properties** file located in **src/main/resources**

I have a application with two packages: **com.test.pkg1** and **com.test.pkg2**.

The class with the **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is located in **com.test.pkg1**.

All the classes inside this package can read with no problem the properties file using the **@Value("${prop_name}")** annotation.

When I use the same method to read properties from **com.test.pkg2**, I only got the placeholder name.

**Example**:

Log from a class from **com.test.pkg1**

Prop value = test //Good!

Log from a class from **com.test.pkg2**

Prop value = ${prop_name} //Why?

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some annotations, but I'm kinda lost.

Thank you.

P.S: I'm using Spring boot 3.1.6 and I used spring initializr for the initial setup. My IDE is Eclipse 2023-06

Answer (score 1):

issue might be related to the component scanning configuration of your Spring Boot application. By default, the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation includes the package where it is located and its subpackages for component scanning. Therefore, the classes in `com.test.pkg1` are picked up automatically, but classes in `com.test.pkg2` might not be.
Ensure that the classes in `com.test.pkg2` are being scanned by Spring. You can explicitly include the package in the @SpringBootApplication annotation, like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.test.pkg1", "com.test.pkg2"})
public class YourApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: IIRC, `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test")`  should also be sufficient.